# How to create video,audio chat system in rails,ruby or using node

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, videochat

I want to build video/audio chat application for my one of the social apps.Is there any library are available in java or ruby or node.js that can help us to build audio/video chat application.

Or any suggestion/technical article that help us to build video chat application.

Answer (score 0):

The xmpp protocol is a good start. There are a lot of implementations for servers where some support video conferencing. There is a lot of support for various languages including ruby, java and even a basic implementation for node(http://github.com/astro/node-xmpp) if thats your thing.

http://www.xmpp.org

Comment: Thank you can you give me basic example for video conferencing How it is implemented jUst basic Overview.

Answer (score 0):

Try Raydash.com, this has plugin for rails for video chat.

You can find the plugin at github

Comment: raydash is web service that provide video chat.but i want to build end to end solutions thanks by the way